# Problems with GRASS tools in QGIS 3.28 LTR

Tags: qgis-3, grass-gis

I've tried to use GRASS tools, like v.clean and v.buffer, and only got those error messages:

```
QGIS version: 3.28.4-Firenze

QGIS code revision: fd0fb72ab3
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.6.2
GEOS version: 3.11.1-CAPI-1.17.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.1.1, December 1st, 2022
PDAL version: 2.4.3 (git-version: f8d673)
Algorithm started at: 2023-03-14T16:03:16
Algorithm 'v.clean' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-b' : False, '-c' : False, 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : False, 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'error' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'input' : 'J:/GIS_Data/data2/5_multiparts/s9_gv_grass.shp', 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'threshold' : '', 'tool' : [0], 'type' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] }

Attempting to use v.external for direct layer read
g.proj -c wkt="I:/GIS_Data/TMP/processing_fTslnw/a0e6c4ac80f54b059f67e880e156e3e2/crs.prj"
v.external input="J:\GIS_Data\data2\5_multiparts\s9_gv_grass.shp" output="vector_64108cb5365494" --overwrite -o
g.region n=0.0 s=0.0 e=0.0 w=0.0
v.clean input=vector_64108cb5365494 type="point,line,boundary,centroid,area,face,kernel" tool="break" output=output020e38d5362d4a34b932535b80f898dc error=error020e38d5362d4a34b932535b80f898dc --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="auto" input="output020e38d5362d4a34b932535b80f898dc" output="I:\GIS_Data\TMP\processing_fTslnw\8eaf750fcfec4f11b333a590fd574572\output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="auto" input="error020e38d5362d4a34b932535b80f898dc" output="I:\GIS_Data\TMP\processing_fTslnw\bda8212aa8134903b9f0d508fbbc3c58\error.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
FEHLER: Unable to create temporary directory <grass7-Third-69104>! Exiting.
Beende...
FEHLER: Unable to create temporary directory <grass7-Third-74300>! Exiting.
Beende...
Execution completed in 1.31 seconds
Results:
{'error': 'I:\\GIS_Data\\TMP\\processing_fTslnw\\bda8212aa8134903b9f0d508fbbc3c58\\error.gpkg',
'output': 'I:\\GIS_Data\\TMP\\processing_fTslnw\\8eaf750fcfec4f11b333a590fd574572\\output.gpkg'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• I:/GIS_Data/TMP/processing_fTslnw/8eaf750fcfec4f11b333a590fd574572/output.gpkg
• I:/GIS_Data/TMP/processing_fTslnw/bda8212aa8134903b9f0d508fbbc3c58/error.gpkg
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Does somebody knows if there is a problem with this version of QGIS and GRASS?

Further more temporary directories can't be created.

Comment: What type of layer were you inputting and what were your input parameters in the v.clean or v.buf toolset?  If you were simply buffering a polygon(s) you might set the input layer type to area, put in your buffer in the map units and set the output type to area and see if that works.  You might also run a check validity tool to make sure you have no geometry errors in your input as a matter of course when a tool fails.

Comment: Also: is `I:\GIS_Data\TMP\` writable?

Comment: After I resetted my QGIS 3 the tool woorked. There are also some problems if one uses more than one version of QGIS 3.